# poetry error "'setup.py' [...] not found" when it exists

Tags: python, python-poetry, jaro-winkler

I'm migrating my packaging tool for a Python project from `pipenv` to `poetry`.

However, when attempting to install `jaro-winkler` (using `poetry add jaro-winkler`), I get the following error:

```
  • Installing jaro-winkler (2.0.1.linux-x86_64): Failed

  EnvCommandError

Command ['/Users/user/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/project-K9Q4AUpY-py3.8/bin/pip', 'install', '--no-deps', 'file:///Users/user/Library/Caches/pypoetry/artifacts/45/cc/59/250d5db2cbcb15286dbae09b9f00727ea007ee685834709a5ac2772716/jaro_winkler-2.0.1.linux-x86_64.tar.gz'] errored with the following return code 1, and output: 
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple
  Processing /Users/user/Library/Caches/pypoetry/artifacts/45/cc/59/250d5db2cbcb15286dbae09b9f00727ea007ee685834709a5ac2772716/jaro_winkler-2.0.1.linux-x86_64.tar.gz
  ERROR: file:///Users/user/Library/Caches/pypoetry/artifacts/45/cc/59/250d5db2cbcb15286dbae09b9f00727ea007ee685834709a5ac2772716/jaro_winkler-2.0.1.linux-x86_64.tar.gz does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.
```

My first thought was to check the `jaro-winkler` project on Github to check that there is indeed a `setup.py` or `pyproject.toml` file, as per the error message `... does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found`.

But it's clear **there is** a setup.py file, see [here](https://github.com/richmilne/JaroWinkler).

Why is poetry failing to find it and install it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package is not installed from GitHub. It is installed from PyPi. And there the content of the file looks unexpected. See https://pypi.org/project/jaro-winkler/2.0.1/#files